# How to see debug logs from my Opendaylight project

Tags: java, debugging, opendaylight

I created a project using MD-SAL Startup Archetype and added some debug logs to check the code. The project is compiled and installed successfully. But after running karaf and log:display, I can't seem me to find any of the logs I entered.
I'm new using ODL and probably am missing something. Can someone help me on how to search for the logs I need?
For example, I read somewhere that we can do `setLogLevelorg.opendaylight.bundlename TRACE or DEBUG` for a specific bundle but in my case, the startup archetype created a folder containing several other from api, features, karaf to impl folders. I added code mainly in the impl folder and created different classes, each of these classes have debug logs that I wanted to check, so how do I specify the bundle name and path in this case? And where should I use that code? Because in the karaf console I can only do `log:list, log:display DEBUG`, etc.
I'm sorry if this a confusing question but would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bundle name you specify with the set log level command but a fully-qualified Java package or class name. You can also just edit *etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg* directly to set the log levels for packages/classes, for example:

`log4j.logger.org.opendaylight.mypackage=DEBUG`

In code you create Logger instances per class, for example:

```
package org.opendaylight.mypackage;

public class MyClass {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    ...
}
```

Log output goes to *data/log/karaf.log*.

Answer (score 2):

From the karaf CLI you can execute below commands.

1. To set log levels for particular package.

   ```
   log:set debug <your package name>
   ```
2. To view logs

   ```
   log:tail
   ```